# Unable to change the x coordinate of Rect object for each item in a list

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently trying to draw a pipe for each item in a list so that I have multiple objects on the screen.

```
    def draw(self):
        for i in pipes:
            self.top_rect = pygame.draw.rect(
                DISPLAYSURF,YELLOW,((self.__x + (i * 100)), ((self.__y - self.__h) - 185), self.__w, self.__h),
            )
```

However when I try to make it so the x coordinate changes for each pipe, I get, "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Pipe' and 'int's" (the class is called Pipe). This issue does not occur if I change it from `pipes` to `range(pipes)`. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So currently, your `for` loop is looping through instances of the class `Pipe`, what you need to do instead is this:

```
for j, i in enumerate(pipes):
    self.top_rect = pygame.draw.rect(
                DISPLAYSURF,YELLOW,((self.__x + (j * 100)), ((self.__y - self.__h) - 185), self.__w, self.__h),
            )
```

`enumerate` provides two values, the current iteration count and the value of the iteration, so here, `j` is the iteration count and `i` is the iterated value of the list `pipes`.

**Notice I swapped out `i` for `j` in the `draw` call**

Comment: Thanks for this! The only reason I didn't do it like this is because I know its not very 'pythonic' as far as what the textbook way is. Would it also be possible to explain why it doesn't just work with my method?

Comment: I did explain in the first line but I'll go further, the list `pipes` is a list of class instances, just looping through that will give you each class instance in the list, it won't give you the current iteration count, using `enumerate` allows you to get the current iteration count and the item in the list, so each time it loops you will get this `(1, Pipe())`, obviously change those for the actual values each loop but thats what it essentially is.

Comment: Ah ok that helps a lot, cheers!